# I can't find ROS when I use CMAKE to compile

Tags: cmake, ros

I am using a software which connects to ROS, when I compile the package by Cmake, I meet the error "Can't find ROS package"

I have added the ROS directory to "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH",but it failed. And I check the ROS package , I can't find the relevant files.

ERROR:

```
CMake Error at applications/plugins/SoftRobots/CMakeLists.txt:190
(find_package):
By not providing "FindROS.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project 
has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "ROS", 
but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ROS" with any of
the following names:

ROSConfig.cmake
ros-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "ROS" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "ROS_DIR"
to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "ROS" provides a
separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

Cmake.list

```
find_package(ROS QUIET REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "ROS found: ${ROS_FOUND}")
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

ROS is not a single package, it is a collection of packages. ROS is simply a name associated with the main aptitude package `ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-desktop-full`, and has nothing to do with CMake.

## END TL;DR

Usually, somebody converts their code to ROS so that they can access the built-in functionality of networked comms with prebuilt message types and libraries to access sensors with hardware (though you don't need robot hardware to use ROS).

ROS is simply an abstraction of communication. If you want the libraries from ROS in your project, then I suggest you use the build-sytem `catkin`. `catkin` is what [links together](https://wiki.ros.org/catkin/conceptual_overview) all of the ROS packages so that you can then use them in your CMake files.

I suggest you follow [this link](https://answers.ros.org/question/249055/how-do-i-include-the-header/) where somebody shows their CMakeLists.txt file. The important part that you need to understand is this:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  genmsg
  message_generation
  depend_1
  depend_2
)


catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS include
   LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
   CATKIN_DEPENDS
   DEPENDS system_lib

)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

And then towards the end, after you have defined your executable,

```
target_link_libraries(run_${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

I should note that I am not testing any of this CMake for verification. The point here is to illustrate how to get the packages that you want from the ROS ecosystem. Once you have the CMake correct, you can simply `#include` the correct header files. What is going on is that CMake is "invoking" `catkin` to find the required packages (refer to the links above for more details). It sounds like, given the fact that you are trying to "import ROS", that you are less than experienced with ROS (which is okay, I was a newbie too), and that this is not a ROS package, but rather a separate project that can be simplified using the libraries given in the ROS ecosystem. I have to say though, since you are quite a ways off the correct method for including ROS, I am not entirely sure how else more to help since you don't provide details in the question why you want ROS in the first place.

(If this answers your question, that green check mark is friendly :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact I am using a plugin which includes ROS. Do you mean it should not find the ros package because it does not exist, so I should invoke some specific packages?
But in the directory: opt/ros/ros/kinetic/share/ros
what 's this package?

Comment: What I mean to say is that "ROS" is not a package in the traditional sense of a CMake package. ROS is a collection of packages that are invoked with the `catkin` build system. The directory you mention points to the packages that are available to be called by `catkin` in your cmake file THAT ARE PRE-COMPILED. In other words, you don't have to recompile them with `catkin_make` or CMake or anything - you can just grab them. They follow the same structure as your catkin workspace, just not in your catkin workspace. Does that make sense?